# How can i disable internet connectivity in Android Emulator with Appium?

Tags: java, android-emulator, appium, android-wifi, connectivity

I want to test the connectivity icon in 3 cases :

1. When the connection status is fine
2. When few heartbeats were missed and/or if the web socket is closed.
3. When no internet

In Case one i can test it because i'm always connected to the internet but others i can't.

PS: I'm using TestNG with Appium and Java

What do you suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.ConnectionType = ConnectionType.None;
```

Or something like this. In this case `driver` is AndroidDriver instance for appium tests

Answer (score 1):

i use the below code to stop wifi connection in ios :

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    rt.exec("networksetup -setairportpower en0 off");
    System.out.println("Wifi OFF Successfully");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

use below to on wifi:

```
rt.exec("networksetup -setairportpower en0 on");
```